# Process N lists simultaneously by doing permutations

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I'm trying to see if someone can come up with a better solution for this algorithm.

I have an input of three lists/queues and I have to group/sort the elements of `xpn`, `tu`, and `efx` — depending on the presence (or not) of `UniqueKey`. For instance, if `UniqueKey` exists, I have to try to form a list/tuple of `xpn`, `tu`, and `efx` (if they exists for that `UniqueKey`)...and so on.

This is the "main" class:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public final class Request {
  private Map<String, List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>>> result;

  private Queue<Node> xpn;

  private Queue<Node> tu;

  private Queue<Node> efx;

  public Map<String, List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>>> transform() {
    final int max = estimateSize();
    result = new LinkedHashMap<>(max / 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      pollFrom(xpn).ifPresent(it -> process(it, Category.XPN));
      pollFrom(tu).ifPresent(it -> process(it, Category.TU));
      pollFrom(efx).ifPresent(it -> process(it, Category.EFX));
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
  }

  private int estimateSize() {
    final int[] sizes = { sizeOf(xpn), sizeOf(tu), sizeOf(efx) };
    int max = sizes[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < sizes.length; i++) {
      if (sizes[i] > max) { max = sizes[i]; }
    }
    return max;
  }

  private Optional<Node> pollFrom(final Queue<Node> collection) {
    return (null != collection) ? Optional.ofNullable(collection.poll()) : Optional.empty();
  }

  private void process(final Node thiz, final Category category) {
    if (result.containsKey(thiz.getUniqueKey())) {
      final List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>> values = result.get(thiz.getUniqueKey());
      final Optional<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>> optional = values.stream()
        .filter(tuple3 -> emptyBucket.apply(tuple3, category))
        .findFirst();
      if (optional.isPresent()) {
        final Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tuple3 = optional.get();
        if (Category.XPN == category) {
          tuple3.update1(thiz);
        } else if (Category.TU == category) {
          tuple3.update2(thiz);
        } else {
          tuple3.update3(thiz);
        }
      } else {
        result.get(thiz.getUniqueKey()).add(tupleFrom(thiz, category));
      }
    } else {
      final List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>> list = new LinkedList<>();
      list.add(tupleFrom(thiz, category));
      result.put((null != thiz.getUniqueKey()) ? thiz.getUniqueKey() : IdGen.uuid(), list);
    }
  }

  private BiFunction<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>, Category, Boolean> emptyBucket = (tuple, category) -> {
    if (Category.XPN == category) {
      return null == tuple._1();
    } else if (Category.TU == category) {
      return null == tuple._2();
    } else { // EFX
      return null == tuple._3();
    }
  };

  private Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tupleFrom(final Node thiz, final Category category) {
    final Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> empty = new Tuple3<>(null, null, null);
    switch (category) {
      case XPN:
        return empty.update1(thiz);
      case TU:
        return empty.update2(thiz);
      case EFX:
        return empty.update3(thiz);
    }
    return empty;
  }

  private int sizeOf(final Collection<Node> collection) {
    return (null != collection) ? collection.size() : 0;
  }

  private enum Category {
    XPN, // 1st element in tuple
    TU,  // 2nd element in tuple
    EFX  // 3rd element in tuple
  }
}
```

The content of `Node` and `Tuple3` are irrelevant, but I can post it if that may help. I'm just trying to see if there is a better way of doing this. The reason you don't see a constructor is because that class is being constructed/deserialized via Jackson. I would really like to avoid having `result` at class level.

**PS:** Don't mind about the method/variable names.

Comment: I don't think I understand your grouping. I can tell what your code is doing ... but why? If a node has a unique key, can you really have more than 1 of those keys? I would expect at most 1 tuple of nodes with the same key which would greatly simplify the code.

Comment: A tuple can have, by unique key, one (two or three) element(s) of `XPN`, `TU`, and `EFX`. You can have another tuple for the same unique key with (almost) the same elements. The data is like that, hence the use of a `List` and not a `Set`. For a given unique key, you need to figure it out how many elements of `XPN`, `TU`, and `EFX`, filling up the tuples whenever you find one of those. You build a new tuple for the same unique key when you find two elements of, for instance, `XPN`, `TU`, or `EFX`...and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're making it so hard on yourself. Why not just go through each of the 3 queues individually?

For the first queue, just go through it and make a new Node for each element. Add it to your result list.

For the other 2 queues, check if the index is already in the result list. If it is, add it to that node, otherwise create a new node.

---

EDIT it seems my point wasn't clear, so let me show you the difference:

```
public Map<String, List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>>> transform2() {
    Map<String, List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(estimateSize() / 3);

    for (Node node : xpn) {
        if (!result.containsKey(node.getUniqueKey())) {
            result.put(node.getUniqueKey(), new LinkedList<>());
        }
        result.get(node.getUniqueKey()).add(new Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>(node, null, null));
    }

    for (Node node : tu) {
        if (!result.containsKey(node.getUniqueKey())) {
            result.put(node.getUniqueKey(), new LinkedList<>());
        }
        List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>> tuples = result.get(node.getUniqueKey());
        boolean needNew = true;
        for (Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tuple : tuples) {
            if (tuple._2() == null) {
                tuple.update2(node);
                needNew = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (needNew) {
            tuples.add(new Tuple3<>(null, node, null));
        }
    }

    for (Node node : efx) {
        if (!result.containsKey(node.getUniqueKey())) {
            result.put(node.getUniqueKey(), new LinkedList<>());
        }
        List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>> tuples = result.get(node.getUniqueKey());
        boolean needNew = true;
        for (Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tuple : tuples) {
            if (tuple._3() == null) {
                tuple.update3(node);
                needNew = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (needNew) {
            tuples.add(new Tuple3<>(null, null, node));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I personally find this a lot easier to understand than all your indirections and switches.

If you really don't want to have one big method you can also split it up like this:

```
public Map<String, List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>>> transform() {
    Map<String, List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>>> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(estimateSize() / 3);

    for (Node node : xpn) {
        Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tuple = getTupleToModify(result, node.getUniqueKey(), (n -> null == n._1()));
        tuple.update1(node);
    }

    for (Node node : tu) {
        Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tuple = getTupleToModify(result, node.getUniqueKey(), (n -> null == n._2()));
        tuple.update2(node);
    }

    for (Node node : efx) {
        Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tuple = getTupleToModify(result, node.getUniqueKey(), (n -> null == n._3()));
        tuple.update3(node);
    }
    return result;
}

private Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> getTupleToModify(
        Map<String, List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>>> currentTuples,
        String key, Function<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>,
        Boolean> filter) {

    if (!currentTuples.containsKey(key)) {
        currentTuples.put(key, new LinkedList<>());
    }

    List<Tuple3<Node, Node, Node>> list = currentTuples.get(key);
    for (Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> tuple : list) {
        if (filter.apply(tuple)) {
            return tuple;
        }
    }
    Tuple3<Node, Node, Node> result = new Tuple3<>(null, null, null);
    list.add(result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what that snippet is doing, but I don't traverse each list separately, but all at once (up to the longest one). The "grouping" has to be done no matter what.

Comment: My point was that by handling the lists seperately you can keep things simpler because you know at that point which case you're working on instead of always using the enum and switches. I updated my answer with how I would implement the method (although a higher level redesign might be in order to further improve the code).